# Checking Data from multiple database and multiple table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a code that checks data from multiple databases having the similar table. so I made an array of databases and table in which I want to check the data is present or not as given below

```
$DatabaseDetails=array(
    array('DatabaseName'=>'database1','TableName'=>'table1'),
    array('DatabaseName'=>'database2','TableName'=>'table2'),
    array('DatabaseName'=>'database3','TableName'=>'table3')
);
```

Then I tried some code that if it does not find the data in 1st database it move to second one and so on until it find the data else **"print no data in database"** but i didn't get the expected result. I am new to php  so have not much idea. So any help is highly appreciated and Thank you in advance. My code is given below.

```
<?php

class FindData{
    public $DatabaseDetails=array(
        array('DatabaseName'=>'database1','TableName'=>'table1'),
        array('DatabaseName'=>'database2','TableName'=>'table2'),
        array('DatabaseName'=>'database3','TableName'=>'table3')
    );

    public function SqlData(){
        $i=0;
        $count=count($this->DatabaseDetails);
        $email="ileee@example.com";
        $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','',$this->DatabaseDetails[$i]['DatabaseName']);
        $sql="select * from ".$this->DatabaseDetails[$i]['TableName']." where email='".$email."'"
        ;
        $run=$this->Data(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
        if(strpos($run,'No data')!==false){
            $i+=1;
        }else{
            echo $run;
        }
    }

    public function Data($run){
        if($run){
            $num=mysqli_num_rows($run);
            if($num>=1){
                return "Data is in presented"; 
            }else{
                return "No data";
            }
        }
    }

}
$obj=new FindData();
$obj->SqlData();
```

?>

Comment: What you are getting now

Comment: array('DatabaseName'=>'database2','TableName'=>'table2'), here you given two quotes in your code check that

Comment: That is a mistake when i am putting the code here.The main code is given below.Any help is highly appreciated. If I am checking for st database data it is showing fine but is not lopping for other database in array

Comment: Sorry, I had to put the smack down on it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not looping over the databases

```
public function SqlData(){
    $i=0;
    $count=count($this->DatabaseDetails);
    $email="ileee@example.com";
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','',$this->DatabaseDetails[$i]['DatabaseName']);
    $sql="select * from ".$this->DatabaseDetails[$i]['TableName']." where email='".$email."'"
    ;
    $run=$this->Data(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
    if(strpos($run,'No data')!==false){
        $i+=1;
    }else{
        echo $run;
    }
}
```

Even if you call this function multiple times externally, you are not changing the `$i` value. So you only use the `$i=0` database.

You try to update it here

```
if(strpos($run,'No data')!==false){
    $i+=1;
}
```

But because there is no loop in the method, and it's a local value. There is either no iteration done or the value of `$i` is reset to `0` on each call to the method.  As I said it's unclear if the method is called once or multiple times to provide the iteration.  In either case it doesn't matter.

So there are 3 ways to fix this.

- add a loop inside the method
- pass in the value of `$i` as an argument (multiple external calls)
- pass in the value of `$i` as an argument (recursive call)

Make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Thanks, everyone, for all the help and suggestions. Below is my code:

```php
<?php
class FindData{
    public $DatabaseDetails=array(
        array('DatabaseName'=>'database1','TableName'=>'table1'),
        array('DatabaseName'=>'database2','TableName'=>'table2'),
        array('DatabaseName'=>'database3','TableName'=>'table3')
    );

    public function SqlData(){      
        $email="patelbhai16@gmail.com";
        $count=count($this->DatabaseDetails);
        $i=0;
        foreach($this->DatabaseDetails as $key =>$value){
            $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','',$value['DatabaseName']);
            if($con){
                $sql="select * from ".$value['TableName']." where email='".$email."'";
                $run=$this->Data(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
                if(strpos($run,'No data')!==false){
                    $i++;
                    if($i==$count){
                        if(strpos($run,'No data')!==false){
                            echo "No data";
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    echo $run;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }       

    }

    public function Data($run){
        if($run){
            $num=mysqli_num_rows($run);
            if($num>=1){
                return "Data is in presented"; 
            }else{
                return "No data";
            }
        }
    }

}
$obj=new FindData();
$obj->SqlData(); 
?>
```

it may help someone in future.